# Getting "subject" value of course by API Google Classroom

Tags: google-classroom

How can I get or update the "subject" value for a course in the API? I did not find any information on this in the documentation

https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/get?authuser=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT

There is a separate subject field when you are filling out a course as R1KO pointed out.

[image]

However, as can be seen by the full response of the `courses` object below, there is *no such field in the API*.

I have called further endpoints to see if it was buried somewhere else but I cannot find it. Looking on the Issue Tracker however, revealed this Feature Request:

> #### [*Add Subject to Course*](https://issuetracker.google.com/156289085)
>
> https://issuetracker.google.com/156289085

So it seems like the best thing you can do at this time is to go and click on the ☆ button in that feature to let Google know that you want this feature.

---

#### The 'subject' is the 'name' in the API

This is the whole `courses` object:

```json
{
  "id": string,
  "name": string,
  "section": string,
  "descriptionHeading": string,
  "description": string,
  "room": string,
  "ownerId": string,
  "creationTime": string,
  "updateTime": string,
  "enrollmentCode": string,
  "courseState": enum (CourseState),
  "alternateLink": string,
  "teacherGroupEmail": string,
  "courseGroupEmail": string,
  "teacherFolder": {
    object (DriveFolder)
  },
  "courseMaterialSets": [
    {
      object (CourseMaterialSet)
    }
  ],
  "guardiansEnabled": boolean,
  "calendarId": string
}
```

The description of the `name` field is as follows:

> Name of the course. For example, "10th Grade Biology". The name is required. It must be between 1 and 750 characters and a valid UTF-8 string.
>
> https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses

You can get this with the `GET` request:

> https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/get

To get all the fields listed above, make sure to include `*` as the fields parameter.

Update with the `UPDATE` or `PATCH`:

> https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/update
> https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/patch

Comment: Form: https://pasteboard.co/JXfQ9Fc.png


Class name is a "name", but "Subject" is not presented: 


https://pasteboard.co/JXfR2LE.png

Comment: @R1KO  yes you are right, I have updated my answer, it looks like there is already a feature request for this.